# eclipse loadproperties like in ant task

Tags: eclipse, ant, properties, debugging

is there something like the anttask loadproperties in eclipse so that i can load a properties file when i want to debug in eclipse.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your Debug Configuration, in the `(x)=Arguments` tab, a VM argument with the properties you want.

```
java -Darg1=foo1 -Darg2=foo2  -Darg3=foo3 com.MyClass
```

, for you to [get their properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).
But if you have so many of them you need a file, then, without an ant execution wrapper, you need to [pass that '`file.properties`' file](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) (this time as a "Program argument") to your program, and read it][2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) (but directly within your code).